# How to hook the appearence of ScrollBar in Memo?

Tags: delphi, winapi, scrollbar, message, memo

Does anybody know what message is sent when the scroll appears on a `TMemo`?

I have a `TMemo` with a scrollbar. I want to decrease the font size upon text filling the window.

I decided: when the scroll appears -> decrease the font. But how to spot the moment when the scroll appears? What is the message?

Comment: You could try something like `Memo1.Font.Height := Memo1.Height div (Memo1.Lines.Count+1);` in `OnChange` event. I use +1 line in order to compensate the fact that just stepping to new line using Enter key doesn't increase the number of lines since the new line character is a part of the previous line. Without this first line would be hidden until at least one character is written to the last line. Of course you may want to start changing text height if number of lines exceeds certain amount. This however does not work if single line is split into multiple because it is too long.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What makes you think there is ANY message sent when a scrollbar appears?